# control flag setup in serial communication

Tags: serialization, serial-port

I am new to serial communication and I have two questions:

1-what is the difference between using | and & when stepping control flags?
2- How to configure an existing termios structure “options” to comply with 6O2 serial port configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking questions related to programming issues where you have a specific programming problem that you have difficulty resolving.

Comment: Also Do I have to add PARENB before setting it to PARODD. Or I can just write PARODD alone?